# Aggregate a field based on time interval

Tags: python, django, models

I have a model like this:

```
class MyModel(Model):
    pub_date = DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    hours = IntergerField()

    def get_weekly_hours(self)
        # Find a week-ago interval based on the pub_date
        # Then based on the interval found above, aggregate the...
        # Sum the `hours` altogether
        pass
```

How grab the time interval, then sum based on that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from datetime import timedelta
from django.db.models import Sum
from django.utils import timezone

MyModel.objects.filter(
    pub_date__gte=timezone.now() - timedelta(days=7)
).aggregate(sum_hours=Sum('hours'))
```

Answer (score 0):

please  check  next  links:

1. [timedelta](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects)
2. [range](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/querysets/#range)
3. [aggregation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/aggregation/)

Comment: Thanks for the links. Dived in and helped me understand better.